# Why would one need to remove any cable connected to the 2nd USB-C port when charging an Apple Watch?

Tags: charging, apple-watch

I am read on the [Anker USB C Charger, 735 Charger (Nano II 65W) Amazon page](https://smile.amazon.com/Anker-Charger-Compact-Foldable-MacBook/dp/B09C5RG6KV):

> When using the USB-A port to charge the Apple Watch, first remove any cable connected to the 2nd USB-C port.

[image]

Why would one need to  remove any cable connected to the 2nd USB-C port when charging an Apple Watch?

[Would an Apple Watch charge any quicker if connected to a 12W USB power adapter?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/393247/20338) and https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250108601 mention that 12W should be more than enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reddit user [SlashedM](https://www.reddit.com/user/SlashedM) mentions that this limitation stems from the fact that Apple Watch and charger constantly renegotiates its power draw:

> Seems like the AW charger does something weird, even Ugreen’s 100W doesn't want you using the AW charger in combination, normally with PD devices, charging stops when a new device is connected due to renegotiation of current distribution.
>
> Apple’s cables also weirdly normally makes the adapter renegotiate even when its just the cable plugged it. So it sounds like (according to ugreen) that the Watch and charger constantly renegotiates its power draw. Its weird, never really seen that before.
>
> https://www.amazon.com/ask/questions/Tx3DLM020L5VWP7/
>
> > Due to the charging mechanism of the apple watch, the current will be redetected to 0 every 2 or 3 mins, causing the watch to disconnect and reconnect automatically, then the current of the wall charger will be redistributed again every 2 or 3 mins. Thus all devices will keep flickering the charge on and off every 2-3 minutes. In this case, it is not suggested to charge the apple watch with other devices at the same time when you decide to charge multiple devices.

Reddit user [docinsfca](https://www.reddit.com/user/docinsfca) mentions that this limitation also affects the Anker 733.